# Toolbar menu in Kendo UI grid cell, which row was menu clicked from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid in which the first column contains a menu where the user can select an Action to perform on the item.

I am using a Kendo UI toolbar, with only the overflow icon (I could not find a better option, there seems to be no standalone drop down *menu* in the suite).

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <div kendo-grid="lineGrid" k-options="lineGridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

MyController.js, column definitions:

```
columns: [{
    field: "Action",
    template: "<div id='lineToolbarDiv' kendo-toolbar='lineToolbar' k-options='lineToolbarOptions' class='button-group-toolbar'></div>",
    width: "80px",
    attributes: { lineNo: "#= lineNo #" }
  }, {
    field: "itemNo", title: "Item #"
  }
  ],
```

MyController.js, toolbar definition:

```
$scope.lineToolbarOptions = {
        items: [{
            type: "button", id: "menuItemA", text: "Do A", overflow: "always"
        }, {
            type: "button", id: "menuItemB", text: "Do B", overflow: "always"
        }],
        click: function (e) {
            console.log("click", e.target.text());
            if (e.id.indexOf("menuItemA") === 0) {
              alert(e.id);
            } else if (e.id.indexOf("menuItemB") === 0) {
              alert(e.id);  
            }
        }
    };
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/FJJmoKyAh3JoOVicUGKB?p=preview

**Question: In the above click handler for the toolbar, how do I know what row they used the menu on?**

Also, if there is a cleaner standalone Kendo menu or similar (that matches the blueopal theme), that could be of interest (and might make this easier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solving your question you need to know that in `click` event handler `this` refer to the `toolbar` and `this.element` is the HTML element.

If you do:

```
click: function(e) {
    // Get the HTML row (tr) that contains the toolbar
    var row = this.element.closest("tr");
    // Get its index in the table
    console.log("row", row.index());
    ...
}
```

If you need to get access to the data item in the Grid DataSource you should use `dataItem` method in KendoUI `grid`. This is something like:

```
click: function(e) {
    // Get the HTML row (tr) that contains the toolbar
    var row = this.element.closest("tr");
    // Get its index in the table
    console.log("row", row.index());
    // Get the item from the Grid DataSource
    var item = $scope.lineGrid.dataItem(row);
    // Show it in the console
    console.log("item", item);
    ...
}
```